# Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x8

Tags: android

I am working on android youtube application. We can fetch data and all the other things perfectly. By using openyoutubeplayer to play the youtube videos. We are passing videoid to play the videos in openyoutubeplayer. While video is playing we encounted with "**Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8" after some time[Its random]**. Please see the following logs.

```
I/NuCachedSource2( 1146): Keep alive
I/NuCachedSource2( 1146): Keep alive
I/NuCachedSource2( 1146): Keep alive
I/NuCachedSource2( 1146): Keep alive
I/NuCachedSource2( 1146): Keep alive
E/InputDispatcher( 1153): channel '4080cb58 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher( 1153): channel '4080cb58 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/IMediaDeathNotifier( 2431): media server died
W/MediaMetadataRetriever( 1243): MediaMetadataRetriever server died!
E/MediaPlayer( 2431): error (100, 0)
I/ServiceManager( 1077): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager( 1077): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager( 1077): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager( 1077): service 'media.audio_policy' died
W/AudioSystem( 2431): AudioFlinger server died!
W/AudioSystem( 1153): AudioFlinger server died!
I/WindowManager( 1153): WINDOW DIED Window{4080cb58 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}
W/AudioSystem( 1153): AudioPolicyService server died!
I/ActivityManager( 1153): Process com.android.launcher (pid 1592) has died.
E/MediaPlayer( 2431): Error (100,0)
D/VideoView( 2431): Error: 100,0
W/WindowManager( 1153): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager( 1153): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@4080c968 does not exist
W/WindowManager( 1153):         at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8181)
W/WindowManager( 1153):         at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8172)
W/WindowManager( 1153):         at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowManagerService.java:7031)
W/WindowManager( 1153):         at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:381)
W/WindowManager( 1153):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/WindowManager( 1153): WIN DEATH: null
I/        ( 2857): ServiceManager: 0xad50
I/CameraService( 2857): CameraService started (pid=2857)
D/AudioHardwareALSA( 2857): openOutputStream called for devices: 0x00000002
I/ALSAModule( 2857): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device AndroidPlayback_Speaker_normal
I/AudioFlinger( 2857): AudioFlinger's thread 0x16c00 ready to run
D/ALSAModule( 2857): route called for devices 00000002 in mode 0...
E/AudioService( 1153): Media server died.
E/AudioService( 1153): Media server started.
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 2857): setPhoneState() setting same state 0
```

while playing the video the log displays "**keep alive**" message. When the video stopped it shows the above log.

I dont know exactly what happens and how to solve this issue.please let me know if u have any ideas.thanks in advance

Comment: if you found answer please post

Answer (score 1):

Keep Alive is an "ping" message between Server's of Youtube and your Client...
If the Client or the Server doesn't receive a keep alive, you lost your connection, break by client or server...

"E/InputDispatcher( 1153): channel '4080cb58 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8"
And here you lost your connection with the server but i don't really know more without code ^^

"W/WindowManager( 1153): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@4080c968 does not exist"
Here you call a windows which doesn't be here? I think your app crash here... Seek it ;)

Answer (score -2):

Please use `android:configChanges="orientation"`  in `AndroidManifest.xml` for the activity that launches your screen.

I was getting the same exception but that was related to camera but usually it causes due to orientation change, the orientation change did not notify the activity so causes the crash.